# Problem while running Cordova build Android

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script 'C:\Users\Aya Morsi\Desktop\CSapp\CS\platforms\android\cordova-support-google-services\starter-build.gradle' line: 16
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.

  > Failed to apply plugin [class 'com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin']
  >   Cannot add extension with name 'googleServices', as there is an extension already registered with that name.
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 8s
cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script 'C:\Users\Aya Morsi\Desktop\CSapp\CS\platforms\android\cordova-support-google-services\starter-build.gradle' line: 16
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.

  > Failed to apply plugin [class 'com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin']
  >   Cannot add extension with name 'googleServices', as there is an extension already registered with that name.
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 8s
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova.

```
    cordova build android exited with exit code 1.

    Re-running this command with the --verbose flag may provide more information.
```

Comment: Just a shot in the dark, try removing the platform ```ionic cordova platform remove android```, then add it again ```ionic cordova platform add android```, after that build it ```ionic cordova build android```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have more than one plugin that uses Google Play Services, perhaps with different versions. There is a plugin that fixes this issue, try to install it and then try to build

https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-android-play-services-gradle-release